# I've got trouble with inner and static inner class at java

Tags: java, inner-classes

Firstly, Thanks everybody that read that topic.  
How can if statement become true in test class? I couldnt find any solution.I couldnt write any code in these method.I tried to send from Room class numberOfTiger to class Question's method but I didnt achieve that.  
That's question about ,How can I change int variable(numberofTiger) to Cat.Tiger variable.After that if statement become true to invoke (getNumberOfTiger) method.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animal an = new Animal();
        Animal.Cat an1 = an.new Cat();
        Animal.Cat.Tiger an2 = an1.new Tiger(3, 900, 2);

        if (Animal.Question.getnumberOfTiger(an2) == 3) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }
    }
}

public class Animal {

    Cat[] c;

    // inner class
    class Cat {

        Tiger[] t;

        // inner class
        class Tiger {
            private int numberOfTiger;
            private int averageOfTigerWeigth;
            private int youngTiger;


            public Tiger(int numberOfTiger, int averageOfTigerWeigth, int youngTiger) {
                super();
                this.numberOfTiger = numberOfTiger;
                this.averageOfTigerWeigth = averageOfTigerWeigth;
                this.youngTiger = youngTiger;
            }

    static class Question {

        static int getnumberOfTiger(Cat.Tiger a) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `class Tiger {     public Room(...) }`?? Please consider posting *real* code, not sort-of kind-of code. Also please format your code so that we don't have to struggle to read it.

Comment: I am so sorry. I edited.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but could you supply some background information please: is this some sort of twisted interview question? If someone brought code like this to me, I'd have it committed long term to a facility for the criminally insane.

Comment: I was about to help.. then i saw the code and how it was formatted... good luck.

Comment: Can you try to rewrite your question? I don't understand anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to either making Cat a static class, or using its instance,

you also need a getter for a.numberOfTiger since it is private, in Tiger class:

```
public getNumberOfTiger() {
return numberOfTiger;
}
```

Then:

```
return a.getNumberOfTiger();
```

Answer (score 0):

In getNumberOfTiger() you need to return the number of tigers associated with that object. You are currently just returning 0, so it will always evaluate to false.

Comment: I know , I ask that How can I return numberOfTiger.If I write anything on return statrment,that s gonna give error.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue. The `Tiger` class and the `Cat` class needs to be `static`. The reason is, a non-static inner class can call on its outer class (e.g. `Cat.this.something`). A non-static inner type is called like this:

```
instanceOfOuterClass.innerClass
```

whereas a static inner type is called like this:

```
outerClassName.innerClass
```

The simplest way to call on a non-static inner type is `new Outer().new Inner();` The main issue with beginners in Java is that they try to do this:

```
new (new Outer()).Inner()
```

But the actual way to call it is

```
new Outer().new Inner()
```

Also, your method is always returning `0` for the count of tigers.